# How to wait undefined callback loop with promises?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, promise, callback

I would like to make my script wait a function which can make a lots of loop himself calls. I saw that I had to use promises, but I don't understand how to use them. Here is my code :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    loadNavbar(0,0); // Load all the nav items at page load
});

function loadNavbar(parentId,state){
    $.get("<?=$http?>://<?=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?>/admin/backTasks/?loadClientNavbar="+parentId, function(data) {
        var navbarItems = JSON.parse(data);
        if (parentId!=0 && data!="[]") {
            $("#item-"+parentId).append("<ul id='parent-"+parentId+"'></ul>");
            //$("#item-"+parentId).appendTo("#parent-"+parentId);
        }
        jQuery.each(JSON.parse(data), function(index){
            $("#parent-"+parentId).append('\
                <li id="item-'+navbarItems[index]["id"]+'">\
                    <div class="modifyNavbarItemList">\
                        <span class="mx-2" id="itemName-'+navbarItems[index]["id"]+'">'+navbarItems[index]["value1"]+'</span>\
                        <button id="btn-'+navbarItems[index]["id"]+'" onclick="modifyItem('+navbarItems[index]["id"]+')" class="ml-auto mr-2 clickable btn btn-sm btn-brown">Modifier</button>\
                    </div>\
                    <div id="modify-'+navbarItems[index]["id"]+'" class="modifyNavbarItemEdit p-2">\
                        <div class="form-group">\
                            <label>Modifier le nom</label>\
                            <input id="modifyName-'+navbarItems[index]["id"]+'" class="form-control form-control-sm clickable" type="text" placeholder="Nom du lien" value="'+navbarItems[index]["value1"]+'">\
                        </div>\
                        <div class="form-group">\
                            <label>Modifier le lien</label>\
                            <input id="modifyLink-'+navbarItems[index]["id"]+'" class="form-control form-control-sm clickable" type="text" placeholder="Lien" value="'+navbarItems[index]["value2"]+'">\
                        </div>\
                        <span><a href="#" class="text-primary mt-n2 clickable" onclick="cancelEdit('+navbarItems[index]["id"]+')">Annuler</a> - \
                        <a href="#" class="text-danger mt-n2 clickable" onclick="deleteItem('+navbarItems[index]["id"]+', false)"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i> Supprimer</a></span>\
                    </div>\
                </li>');
            loadNavbar(navbarItems[index]["id"],1);
        });
    });

    // I actually use a timeout to wait the script finish xD 
    // Not very suitable for bad ADSL connections :p (and not at all)
    if (state===0) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            $('#parent-0').sortableLists( options );
        }, 2000);
    }
}
```

As you can see I used a timeout... But this is not the solution

**EDIT:** I change my backend to create a list of all the navbar elements. So I adapted this code to just read the array, and to avoid calling again the function every time there is a child element.

Comment: You want to do your `sortableLists()` call directly after your `jQuery.each()` call. Callbacks are generally speaking an "alternative" to callbacks. They don't solve any technical problems that callbacks can't do.

Comment: No because It broke the structure, we have to call this func after all the items loaded.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice that your loadNavbar is recursive. This is essentially a DS&A problem (it's normal to struggle with these). Ponder the question of "How can I keep track of the number of navbar items I still need to load?" 
I'll be back tomorrow if you still need help.